How to design sub frames separately and add them up in main application
I'm trying to design and create my python application with Qt Designer (using PyQt5).
My Application happens to have lots of buttons and "sub windows" (frames basically) which is quite frustrating to design all at once.
I am wondering if there's a way to design a Frame or a Widget separately and then kind of "Import" it to the main application window?
I couldn't find any and would love to hear if someone knows a way.

Just create those frames as actual QFrames (select the appropriate widget type in the "New form" dialog of Designer, it also includes standard widgets such as QFrame), then add them to the main window. If you're currently using the loadUi() function to load the .ui files, then do the same for those frames. If you're using the pyuic utility, then build each ui and import the related files. The same goes if you're using other uic functions such as loadUiType().

You can use promoted widgets for that: design frame and save it to ui file myframe.ui, generate ui class file MyFrame.py using pyuic5 (pyuic5 -o MyFrame.py myframe.ui), add Widget to mainwindow.ui and promote it to MyFrame (promoted class name MyFrame, header file MyFrame.py)

thanks for the quick response! but can you add an image of an example? when I try it in the qtdesigner, and run with CTRL+R, i dont see my custom frame in the promoted widget...

The QtDesigner also doesn't inherent from QWidget on my "MyFrame" class... is it something im doing wrong?

@JhonMargalit Widget promotion is mostly intended to use the promoted widget as a placeholder within the current UI in Designer. It does not show the final promoted widget (nor it could), it only shows the base type on which the promoted widget is based upon. The only way to display custom widgets in Designer is through plugins, but doing so is quite complex and requires much more experience (and it's normally unnecessary). I strongly recommend to do some serious and patient research on promoted widgets, as there are plenty of available resources, even here on SO.
